# Why does combining a custom WrappedRequest with extra type parameter and ActionFilter cause the type to be lost?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

Combining an `ActionBuilder` that transforms a request into a custom `WrappedRequest` with an additional type parameter, and then combining that with an `ActionFilter` causes the type of the custom `WrappedRequest` to  be dropped.

Why is this and is there a fix?

For example, lets say I need to an authentication `ActionBuilder` and an optional, authorisation `ActionFilter` where the user type we need can vary depending on use.

See this contrived code:

```
case class AuthRequest[A, U](val request: Request[A], val user: U) extends WrappedRequest[A](request)

case class TestUser(id: String)

case class AuthenticationAction[A]() extends ActionBuilder[({type λ[B] = AuthRequest[B, TestUser]})#λ] {

  override def invokeBlock[A](request: Request[A], block: (AuthRequest[A, TestUser]) => Future[Result]): Future[Result] =
    block(AuthRequest(request, TestUser("test-id")))

}

case class AuthorisedAction[A]() extends ActionFilter[({type λ[B] = AuthRequest[B, TestUser]})#λ] {

  // does some additional authorisation checks for added security
  def authorised(user: TestUser) = true

  override def filter[A](request: AuthRequest[A, TestUser]) = Future.successful {
    if( authorised(request.user) ) None
    else Some(Unauthorized)
  }

}
```

**Please note:** The type function in the above is required as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19345482/48611) because of the additional type parameter on the `AuthRequest`. Again this is required because this API will be used with more than one type of user.

If I then implement a controller that uses the above:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

  def secured = (AuthenticationAction() andThen AuthorisedAction()) { request =>
    Ok(request.user.id)
  }

}
```

I get a compiler error (`value user is not a member of play.api.mvc.WrappedRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]`). In other words, the type of the variable `request` above is `WrappedRequest` instead of the expected type of `AuthRequest[play.api.mvc.AnyContent, TestUser]`!

I understand that most use cases the `AuthenticationAction` and `AuthorisedAction` would be combined into a single action but, because authorisation is optional, I would like to keep these as separate concerns.

Is this possible? Is this a bug in the Play Framework API? Or a Scala bug? Or human error?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example I was able to compose the actions like this:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {
  def secured = AuthorisedAction().compose(AuthenticationAction()) { request =>
    Ok(request.user.id)
  }
}
```

It's interesting to note that in both cases IntelliJ's type inspection sees `request` as being of type `AuthRequest[AnyContent, TestUser]` -- it's only scalac that sees it as a `WrappedRequest`.